# How to check Proxy headers to check anonymity?

Tags: python, http, proxy, anonymity

I'm trying to determine high anonymity proxies. Also called private/elite proxies. From a forum I've read this:

> High anonymity Servers don't send HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, HTTP_VIA and
>   HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION variables. Host doesn't even know you are using
>   proxy server and of course it doesn't know your IP address.
>
> A highly anonymous proxy will display the following information:
>
> REMOTE_ADDR = Proxy's IP address
>
> HTTP_VIA = blank
>
> HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = blank

So, how I can check for this headers in Python, to discard them as a HA Proxy ? I have tried to retrieve the headers for 20-30 proxies using the `requests` package, also with urllib, with the build-in http.client, with urllib2. But I didn't see these headers, never. So I should be doing something wrong...

This is the code I've used to test with `requests`:

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://176.100.108.214:3128'}
header = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.360',}
s = requests.session()
s.proxies = proxies
r = s.get('http://www.python.org', headers=header)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.request.headers)
print(r.headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the forum post you're referring to is talking about the headers seen by the *server* on your proxied request, not the headers seen by the *client* on the proxied response.

Since you're testing with `www.python.org` as the server, the only way to see the headers it receives would be to have access to their logs. Which you don't.

But there's a simple solution: run your own HTTP server, make requests against that, and then you can see what it receives. (If you're behind a firewall or NAT that the proxy you're testing won't be able to connect to, you may have to get a free hosted server somewhere; if not, you can just run it on your machine.)

If you have no idea how to set up and configure a web server, Python comes with one of its own. Just run this script with Python 3.2+ (on your own machine, or an Amazon EC2 free instance, or whatever):

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

class HeaderDumper(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        try:
            return super().do_GET()
        finally:
            print(self.headers)

server = HTTPServer(("", 8123), HeaderDumper)
server.serve_forever()
```

Then run that script with `python3` in the shell.

Then just run your client script, with `http://my.host.ip` instead of `http://www.python.org`, and look at what the script dumps to the server's shell.

Comment: Ok I've understood the client/server trick. And I've remembered the $_SERVER[] PHP var (lol) But That server you wrote would be listening all the time for a new get request. On 127.0.0.1:8123 I guess. It's what the HeaderDumper() does, right ?

Comment: @JesúsFlores: Well, it listens on `0.0.0.0:8123`, not just `127.0.0.1:8123`, which is why the proxy can connect to it (assuming it's on a reachable IP address). But otherwise, yes, it's a server that listens forever for new get requests (and responds with a directory listing of its current directory), and, in addition to printing the normal `127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2015 17:49:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -` log line to the terminal, it also prints out all the headers it sees.